# Uncaught TypeError: elem.nodeName.toLowerCase is not a function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

i am working on a project which was working fine but suddenly today it is showing an TypeError

> Uncaught TypeError: elem.nodeName.toLowerCase is not a function Jquery

below is my code where i got the error

```
// A method for determining if a DOM node can handle the data expando
acceptData: function( elem ) {
    // Do not set data on non-element because it will not be cleared (#8335).
    if ( elem.nodeType && elem.nodeType !== 1 && elem.nodeType !== 9 ) {
        return false;
    }

    var noData = elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()//**here** ];
```

I changed my code a bit and added toStringbefore toLowerCase but still getting the same error,

> changed Like this

```
var noData = elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toString().toLowerCase()//**like this** ];
```

what is the possible problem here?

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(elem.nodeName, typeof elem.nodeName)`?

Comment: Seems `elem` is a jQuery object, Share output of `console.log(elem)`

Comment: change the variable name `elem` to something else

Comment: `console.log(elem) = undefined,
console.log(elem.nodeName) = "DIV"`

Comment: `toLowerCase()` function use for string variables. Here `elem.nodeName=DIV` so you can't use lowercase function for this. first retrieve text of that div in a variable and then apply `toLowerCase()` function on it

Comment: @GSB i think output > DIV is string because it is coming in double codes like "DIV"

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh output > DIV it means your node name ie HTML control  name is DIV. I am assuming you need to lowercase the content inside of this DIV.so retrieve text of that div in a variable and then apply toLowerCase() function on it

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh Can you share a working snippet using `<>` so that you issue can be replicated?

Comment: The code you shared is from jQuery's sources. I am sorry, but I guess you are not really one of jQuery's developers, and that you probably get this error while calling one of jQuery's methods. I think this call is what **we** need in order to help you.

Answer (score 2):

"nodeName" is reserved name by jQuery.
Change it to other name if it's used in your script or in your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Base on Nakama Hiroshi's answer.
I found my mistake.I add name "nodeName" for the input.

```
<input type="text" id="nodeName"  name="nodeName"  />
```

> "nodeName" is reserved name by jQuery

And I change "nodeName" to other name. Then fix the problem