# a.nodeName.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I kept seeing this on my console - and have idea how to get rid of it.

[image]

I click on `(jquery.min.js:2)` I see

[image]

> a.nodeName.toLowerCase is not a function

I don't know how and where is this coming from?

## Code

```
@extends('layouts.admin.master')
@section('content')


<style type="text/css">
.success{
    color: #40B34E;
}

.warning{
    color: #FF5B00;
}

.danger{
    color: #F33734;
}

td .fa  {
    text-align: center;
}


table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}


.fadeInHighlight {
    color:red;
    -webkit-transition:background 3s;
    -moz-transition:background 3s;
    -o-transition:background 3s;
    transition:background 3s;
}


</style>


<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="view-header">
                <div class="pull-right text-right" style="line-height: 14px">

                </div>
                <div class="header-icon">
                    <i class="pe page-header-icon pe-7s-science"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="header-title">
                    <h3 class="m-b-xs">{{ $_GET['nodeName'] }} </h3>
                    <small>
                        This section will summarize the specific Node
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>

    @include('layouts.operation.nodes.show.chart')


    <br>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-filled">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>VNF Instances</h4>
                        <a href="/nodes/{{ $nodeId }}/create?ip={{ $_GET['ip'] }}&port={{ $_GET['port'] }}&nodeId={{ $_GET['nodeId'] }}&nodeName={{ $_GET['nodeName'] }}" class="btn btn-success pull-right"> Create</a>
                    </h4>

                </div>
                <table class="table table-responsive-sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Instance</th>
                            <th>VCPU</th>
                            <th>Memory</th>
                            <th>HDD</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @if($vnfInstances != null)

                        <?php $x = 1; ?>

                        @foreach($vnfInstances as $instance)

                        <?php $instanceId = $instance['instanceId']; ?>

                        <tr id="tr-{{ $instanceId }}">
                            <td>{{ $x++ }}</td>

                            <td>
                                <a href="/nodes/{{ $instanceId }}/summary/1?instanceId={{ trim($instanceId) }}&ip={{ $_GET['ip'] }}&port={{ $_GET['port'] }}&nodeId={{ $_GET['nodeId'] }}&instanceName={{ $instanceId }}&nodeName={{ $_GET['nodeName'] }}">
                                    {{ $instanceId }}
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $instance['vCPUs'] }}</td>

                            <td>
                                @if(array_key_exists('memoryInKB',$instance))
                                {{ number_format($instance['memoryInKB']/1048576,1) }} GB
                                @endif
                            </td>

                            <td>

                                @if(array_key_exists('diskUsedInMB',$instance) && array_key_exists('diskTotalInMB',$instance))

                                {{ $instance['diskTotalInMB'] }}  MB

                                @endif


                            </td>


                            <td class="state-{{ $instanceId }}">{{ $instance['state'] }}</td>
                            <td>

                                {{-- VNV Operation --}}

                                {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form', 'url'=>'nodes/'. $instance['instanceId'] .'/action')) !!}


                                <select class="form-control" name="action-{{ $instanceId }}" onchange="showModal('{{ $instanceId }}')">
                                    <option value="---"> --- </option>

                                    @foreach($instance['operations'] as $operation)
                                    <option value="{{ $operation }}">
                                        {{ basename($operation) }}
                                    </option>

                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="{{ $_GET['ip'] }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="port" value="{{ $_GET['port'] }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="nodeId" value="{{ $_GET['nodeId'] }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="nodeName" value="{{ $_GET['nodeName'] }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="instaneName-{{ $instanceId }}" value="{{ $instanceId }}">

                                {!!Form::close()!!}

                                {{-- VNV Operation --}}


                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        @endforeach

                        @else

                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <td colspan="12">
                                <br>
                                No Data Available
                            </td>

                        </tr>


                        @endif

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @include('layouts.operation.nodes.show.thumnail')
        @include('layouts.operation.nodes.show.interface')
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        @include('layouts.operation.dashboard.nfTable')
    </div>

</div>

</div>
@stop

@section('custom-scripts')

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    function showModal(instance) {

        console.log("showModal executed ... ");
        console.log(`%c ${instance}` , "color: green;");

        var action    = $("select[name=action-" + instance + "]").val();
        var parts     = action.split('/');
        var operation = parts.pop() || parts.pop();  // handle potential trailing slash

        var popupTemplate =
        '<div class="modal fade">' +
        '  <div class="modal-dialog">' +
        '    <div class="modal-content">' +
        '      <div class="modal-header">' +
        '        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>' +
        '        <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure ?</h4>' +
        '      </div>' +
        '      <div class="modal-body">' +
        '        <h4 class="modal-title">You want to ' + operation + '  ' +  instance + ' ?</h4>' +
        '      </div>' +
        '      <div class="modal-footer">' +
        '        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ' +
        '        onclick="updateAction(`'+ instance+'`)">Yes</button>' +
        '        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>' +
        '      </div>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '  </div>' +
        '</div>';

        $(popupTemplate).modal()
    }

    function updateAction(instance) {

        console.log("updateAction executed ... ");


        var data         = {};
        data.ip          = $("input[name=ip]").val();
        data.port        = $("input[name=port]").val();
        data.instaneName = $("input[name=instaneName-" + instance + "]").val();
        data.action      = $("select[name=action-" + instance + "]").val();

        var parts = data.action.split('/');
        var operation = parts.pop() || parts.pop();  // handle potential trailing slash

        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{ URL::to("nodes/1/action")}}',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: false,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('value'),
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            },
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                //console.log(response);

                if(response >= 200 && response <= 207 ){

                    toastr.options = {
                        "debug": false,
                        "newestOnTop": true,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "progressBar": true
                    };

                    toastr.success(data.instaneName + ' - ' +  operation );
                    $("select[name=action-" + instance + "]").prop('selectedIndex',0);
                    $("td[class=state-" + instance + "]").text(operation);

                } else {
                    toastr.options = {
                        "debug": false,
                        "newestOnTop": true,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "progressBar": true
                    };

                    toastr.error(data.instaneName + ' can not ' + operation );
                    $("select[name=action-" + instance + "]").prop('selectedIndex',0);

                }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });

    }

</script>



@include('layouts.operation.nodes.show.scripts.chart')
@stop
```

Comment: It means that `.nodeName` is either `undefined` or `null`, probably

Comment: What line in my code does that ?

Comment: How do u know which line causes that ? The line in the console redirect me to a junk code that is not really human readable.

Comment: It's in jQuery's code, per the traceback. Probably a minified version of [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/core/nodeName.js#L7). `a.nodeName&&a.nodeName.toLowerCase()` -  `a.nodeName` is truthy, but apparently not a string.

Comment: I can't tell from what's posted. Something is calling a jQuery function improperly. jQuery does not have much internal error checking (for performance reasons) so when something goes wrong you get an inscrutable error. Somewhere on the call stack however there should be something from your own code.

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't use `nodeName` in your own code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48072628/3001761

Comment: Check the two lines after ```toastr.success(data.instaneName + ' - ' +  operation );```  Am not sure but aren't you supposed to put double quotes around the name selector like for example : ```$('select[name="action-' + instance + "']').prop('selectedIndex',0);``` Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, you have `nodeName` in your input as its name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nodeName"
```

Use different name, and it will fix the issue. As jQuery already preserve `nodeName`.

Comment: The error is inside jQuery code, so it means that something is improperly making a jQuery call of some sort.

Comment: ahh -- I didn't know that.. no wonder.